# Optional numeric value in text field validation rule

Tags: validation, ms-access-2007

Is there a character in the text field data validation rules for Access 2007 that will only accept numbers but the last numeric entry is optional? E.g. For numeric fields, 000.0009 forces a value to the third decimal but not necessarily to the fourth decimal.  How can I represent this in a text field? Right now I am using ###.###* as my validation rule, but it isn’t exactly what I want.

Need the field as text because data has to be stored with trailing zeroes.

Comment: I take it the data being entered is keyed manually via a form, in which case I would apply the validation to the form before it saves (probably in the BeforeUpdate) and leave the table alone. I can post some code to do this if it is an option.

Comment: Also, does the data have to be stored with trailing zeros or can this be applied to the saved data when pulling it; format([FieldName],"000.0000") would display with trailing zero. 659.2 would display as 659.2000

Comment: User wants it stored with their trailing zeroes intact, not just displayed. They are ID numbers, not numbers to be used in math calculations. The trailing zeroes are part of the ID number.

Comment: Will there always be the same number of characters to the right of the decimal (i.e. always 4, but the user may only enter 1 or 2 and then fill with zeros)? If yes, there is a way to show trailing zeros, but not require entry.

Comment: No. Always three in front of the decimal and three following it, but on very rare occasions there will be a fourth decimal. It's those rare exceptions that kill ya. Number has to be shown exactly as as is. Fourth decimal is only stored if fourth decimal exists.